# Library for file management. Two backends: filesystem, s3

Tags: open-source, library, file-management, python, cloud-storage

I am dreaming of a Python library which abstracts the file handling of my application.

The application should run in two different configurations:

1. No storage server. All file operations get done on the local disk.
2. With storage server. All file operations should get done via s3.

I would like to do [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The application code should not care which configuration gets used. Choosing the right configuration (with or without storage server) gets done via configuration management.

I don't need all file operations which I can do via `os` and `os.path`. I just need all operations which can be done via s3.

Other required features:

- Open source: BSD or LGPL, not GPL
- Support for Linux. Other operating systems are not important in this context.

### Distinction / out off scope

I don't want all file operations (like `os.walk()`). I just need the fundamental storage APIs of s3, but without a running storage server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you give [Siilo](https://github.com/jpvanhal/siilo) a try.

It is a storage abstraction layer for Python.

Siilo gives you a base API with operations like `open` and `delete`, that you can use without worrying about what is being used below.

It supports:

- Local filesystem
- Amazon S3
- Apache Libcloud
- CMIS on [fmerges's branch](https://github.com/fmerges/siilo)

Minus points:

- It seems that very few operations are implemented. If I understand the code correctly, if you need `write` you will have to implement it yourself (in that case please send a pull request)
- No documentation nor code samples
- Community is small and very quiet

Plus points:

- Open source (MIT)
- Very lightweight

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python library to mock out the boto (s3) library:

https://github.com/spulec/moto

> Moto is a library that allows your python tests to easily mock out the boto library

It can run in standalone server mode, if you want to access it from a different programming language